# Problema ao exibir imagem dinâmica com Thymeleaf

Tags: java, ajax, aplicação-web, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Tenho uma aplicação, onde o usuário pode armazenar a foto do perfil.

Salvo a imagem em `C:/imgPerfil/` concatenando o id do usuário com o nome original da imagem. 

Exemplo: "**2teste.jpeg**".

Preciso mostrar essa imagem no front usando `thymeleaf`, como fazer isso? 
O Path é salvo dentro do Objeto usuário na variável foto, também pego os dados por Ajax.

**HTML:**

```
<img id="fotoUsuario" class="circle" th:src="@{usuario.foto}" style="margin-left: 35%"></img>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    var nome;
    var foto;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/getPerfil',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (perfil) {
            nome = perfil[0].nome;
            foto = perfil[0].foto;
            console.log(perfil[0]);
            $("#nomeUsuario").text(nome);
            $("fotoUsuario").attr('src', foto);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Como exibir essa imagem?

Answer (score 0):

O Thymeleaf é uma framework de template, sendo assim, ele vai pegar os dados passados pela controller juntar com o template e gerar o html final que será exibido no browser.

Teoricamente eu não precisaria pegar dinamicamente, já que uma foto de usuário não muda constantemente e caso eu precisasse mudar eu faria um serviço de alteração de foto de perfil de usuário e logo após a alteração da foto, recarregaria a pagina que usa o perfil.

Certifique que o mapeamento das imagens estejam corretos.